Can we ever know the exact polarisation of a given photon?
When we pass photons with randomly orientated polarisations through a vertical polarising filter, half the photons that pass through are said to be vertically polarised, but in reality they have a distribution of angles that are plus or minus 45 degrees from the vertical. If we pass the photons through a polarising beam splitter we know one beam has vertically polarised photons and the other has horizontally polarised photons, but again they are a distribution of various angles.
It is also said the light that is reflected off water or glass is polarised parallel to the water or glass surface, but I suspect the reality is they are not exactly horizontal and the most we can say about them is the horizontal component of the polarisation is greater than the vertical polarisation and repeated reflection will not improve our knowledge of the exact orientations. I'm pretty sure that experiments with entangled photons do not reveal the original polarisation state of the photons when they were prepared or even after they have passed through both analysers and we compare the correlations.
Can we ever prepare a photon in an exact known polarisation state or ever deduce its exact polarisation?

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpolarized_light#Poincar%C3%A9_sphere

What is the difference between "knowing" and "truly knowing" ?

I think you are just asking about the uncertainty principle.
If I have a photon that is KNOWN to be horizontally polarized, then that means that my photon is in a superpostion in a diagonal basis:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1_D\rangle+|1_A\rangle)$
I think you are thinking that this means that my photon was not actually really in the horizontal state (because how can it be in the horizontal state if sometimes its in $|1_D\rangle$ or $|1_A\rangle$)...but this is untrue.
The photon I started out with is exactly 100% in the horizontal polarization 100% of the time. It just means that if I (INSTEAD of measuring if its horizontal or vertical) tried measuring if it was $|1_D\rangle$ or |1_A\rangle, I would get that it's a 50/50 distribution.
Also, just for complete clarity. It is clear to you that if I have a photon that is Horizontally polarized, and I put it through another horizontal polarizer, that it will go through it 100% of the time right? You can certainly prepare single photons to accurately be in a particular polarization, and they will, with 100% accuracy (besides some techincal errors) act as if they are in that polarization.


When we pass photons with randomly orientated polarisations through a vertical polarising filter, half the photons that pass through are said to be vertically polarised, but in reality they have a distribution of angles that are plus or minus 45 degrees from the vertical.

No this statement is not correct. An initial photon with an unknown state of polarization is in an unknown superposition of horizontal and vertical components. We can express it as
$$ |\psi\rangle = |H\rangle\alpha + |V\rangle\beta , $$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown coefficients such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$. What a polarizer does is to absorb one of the two components so that only the other one survives. So a vertical polarizer would absorb the horizontal component, so that we get
$$ |\psi_{\text{out}}\rangle = |V\rangle , $$
after normalization. We can interpret $\beta$ now as the probability amplitude that the photon survives this process. So it is exactly vertically polarized, with no uncertainty.
The same argument can be used for a polarizing beamsplitter. However, physical devices are not perfect (as specified by the extinction ratio.). They always allow a small component of the unwanted polarization through.
When you consider the situation of light reflecting off a dielectric surface the situation becomes more complicated. In that case you need to consider how the Fresnel coefficients modify the two coefficients of the initial state of polarization. In general, it would modify the state of polarization, but at the Brewster angle you can again get a well-defined linear state of polarization.

Did you mean, 2with (no) uncertainty?

@KDP Thanks, fixed it.

It is not possible if you have just one single photon.
However, if you have a photon source, i.e. it has one single density operator = one quantum state, then you can perform the tetrahedron measurement quantum state tomography and just by waiting and collecting enough data, you can pin down the whole density operator. That site also links to papers stating how it can be extended for entangled pairs.

It is also said the light that is reflected off water or glass is polarised parallel to the water or glass surface, but I suspect the reality is they are not exactly horizontal and the most we can say about them is the horizontal component of the polarisation is greater than the vertical polarisation and repeated reflection will not improve our knowledge of the exact orientations.

You are mistaken. What you are talking about is the Brewster's angle, and it is easily provable that this is 100% polarised. It is extremely easy to see why this is true if you consider the vector potential. Sadly, I don't have the time to draw it out for you. Sorry.

I could be wrong, but I don't think he's asking about how we can reconstruct the underlying quantum state. I think he's just asking if the polarization of a photons state can /ever/ be known. It certainly can for eigenstates.

That's the same thing. One would need to know the polarisation state to obtain the density operator. You can look at the website and see them talking about polarisers. The density operator doesnt even need to be any eigenstate.

I dont understand your point. Any photons that successfully travel through a horzontal polarizer will have a very, well-defined horizontal polarization, and will continue to have this "exact polarization" as it propagates. And therefore it is possible to make conclusions about the exact polarization of a single photon without collecting statistics. (Although trying to infer the wavefunction for a state in a superposition of polarizations will require statistical reconstruction.)

No, that is you doing a measurement and thus destroying its initial information. I'm talking about doing a complicated measurement so that waiting for the statistics allows you to reconstruct the photon's quantum state from before the measurement. So that you can characterise what your source actually is sending out.

The question is not "how do you characterise what the quantum state of your source actually is sending out." The question is instead: "can we EVER know the exact polarization of a given photon" (and the answer is yes, we can)

That is your interpretation of the question. I do not agree at any point that your interpretation is anywhere near what the question is asking for.
